# Safe accessing of a file which would have been accessed by another process

Tags: c#, process, console, file-read

I am sending some data to another program over TCP (Numbers to do some calculation). The second program will write the result of the calculation to a text file. I want to access this text file from my console to display the result in my console application. I would like to do it asynchronously.  How do I make sure that writing is over and file can be accessed now. How do I call the async method in main ??

```cs
public static async Task SimpleReadAsync()
{
   string filePath = "C:\\result.txt";
   string text = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

How to call async in main ???
Like this ?

```cs
var result = SimpleReadAsync();
```

Comment: Try to acquire a write lock. If it fails, someone else is writing to it.

Comment: is it possible to show an example ? sorry I am new to async and threadding.

Comment: Heads up, this has nothing to do with async / threading, and everything to do with windows handles and how to gain access and share rights to them (assuming this is windows)

Answer (score 0):

if you are in parralel read/write you should first know if the other program opens the file in exclusive mode or not. if its exclusive you can't read the file while the other program is opening it.

please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access)

hop it can help you

Comment: It is not in parallels read/write. My intention is Send instruction to the program.  Then wait for text write and try to open the file.